# Installed module not visible in admin - Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.3, extensions, cache

I've installed a module and while the **CLI** says that the module is installed, the schema in the db has been created and the module has a record in **setup_module** it doesn't show up in the admin. When looking at the module in the module manager it shows as off, enabling it via the module manager doesn't change this.

I've then installed another module as a test (webshopapps matrixrates), exactly the same thing happens, shows as installed, schema created, shows as off in module manager even if you enable it.

So far I've done a full uninstall of the modules (disabled the module, ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, removed the db entries, deleted the module files and then cleared the cache / re-ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and confirmed the module no longer shows up in the cli or mod manager) and then reinstalled and still no joy.

It feels like something got stuck but I can't figure out whats going on...

Ideas?

Comment: But do you know where the module in admin should be displayed? Check this file `etc/adminhtml/menu.xml`, you can see where you have the module display.

Comment: Yes the module in question is WebShopApps MatrixRates and MageWorx Order Management which should show up in the config panel and the shipping methods section respectively. So it isn't just that I'm not looking in the right place

Comment: Check `system.xml` and see where it is placed.

Comment: Put the `system.xml` file here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out in the end. Complete rookie mistake.

I was getting a lot of inconsistencies between the **CLI** and the admin system. For example setting the cache as enabled or disabled on the **CLI** wasn't affecting the admin cache status, along with the issue of installed modules not displaying.

Turns out it's because I have **APC enabled for php-fpm but not for the CLI**. Quick restart of php-fpm and all is well!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this page

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html

Use the following command to list enabled and disabled modules:

magento module:status

For example, to enable the Weee module, enter:

magento module:enable Magento_Weee

and see if your module listed and enabled

Comment: That is how I've enabled the module, as I said the CLI says the module is enabled but it doesn't appear the the web based module manager says it's off